# Use of uninitialized value $data_directory

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Postgresql server doesn't start  ,  I installed postgresql 9.6 [ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS]

`systemctl status postgresql@9.6-main.service`

```
 postgresql@9.6-main[16944]: Use of uninitialized value $data_directory in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/PgCommon.pm line 215.

postgresql@9.6-main[16944]: Error: Invalid data directory for cluster 9.6 main
```

How can I fix it?

update 1 :

`pg_lsclusters`

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
9.6 main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log
```

`sudo pg_ctlcluster 9.6 main start`

```
Job for postgresql@9.6-main.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration.
See "systemctl status postgresql@9.6-main.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

`systemctl status postgresql@9.6-main.service`

```
Process: 7658 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect 9.6-main start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 09 14:35:25 ubuntu207 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL Cluster 9.6-main...
Apr 09 14:35:25 ubuntu207 postgresql@9.6-main[7658]: Use of uninitialized value $data_directory in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/PgCommon.pm line 215.
Apr 09 14:35:25 ubuntu207 postgresql@9.6-main[7658]: Use of uninitialized value $data_directory in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/PgCommon.pm line 215.
Apr 09 14:35:25 ubuntu207 postgresql@9.6-main[7658]: Error: Invalid data directory for cluster 9.6 main
Apr 09 14:35:25 ubuntu207 systemd[1]: postgresql@9.6-main.service: Can't open PID file /run/postgresql/9.6-main.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Apr 09 14:35:25 ubuntu207 systemd[1]: postgresql@9.6-main.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Apr 09 14:35:25 ubuntu207 systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 9.6-main.
```

update 2 :

my postgresql.conf

```
data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main'     # use data in another directory
                    # (change requires restart)
hba_file = '/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_hba.conf'   # host-based authentication file
                    # (change requires restart)
ident_file = '/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_ident.conf'   # ident configuration file
                    # (change requires restart)

# If external_pid_file is not explicitly set, no extra PID file is written.
external_pid_file = '/var/run/postgresql/9.6-main.pid'          # write an extra PID file
                    # (change requires restart)
```

`~# sudo -u postgres psql`

```
could not change directory to "/root": Permission denied
psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Comment: 1) Postgres 9.6 went EOL in November 2021, are you sure you want to use it? 2) How did you install Postgres and if from a repo what repo? 3) What does `pg_lsclusters` show? **Add answers as update to question**.

Comment: i want to upgrade using version 13 , but my data is in 9.6 , so i want to fetch the data first for backcup

but the problem arose when one time I rebooted the server, postgres couldn't be run

is there any way to retrieve my data in 9.6?

Comment: You could try: `sudo pg_ctlcluster 9.6 main start`.

Comment: the same error, : ` Use of uninitialized value $data_directory `

Comment: 1) Why was the server rebooted and where there any other errors on reboot? 2) Check to see if there is more the one `data_directory` in the `postgresql.conf` file.

Comment: thanks for the advice, btw I fixed it, it's a problem with permissions
I don't know why the permissions can change

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it, it's a problem with the `$data_directory` permission:

```
sudo chmod -R u=rwx '/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/'
sudo chmod -R 0700 '/etc/postgresql/9.6/main'
pg_ctlcluster --foreground 9.6 main start
```

And the result  `pg_ctlcluster` is  :

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
9.6 main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log
```